# PlaceHolderMain controlling td width of hard-coded values

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In my custom .master page I have the following code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

This prints out the main content of my page. It contains this structure

```
<table ID="OuterZoneTable" width="100%">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr id="OuterRow">
        <td width="80%" id="OuterLeftCell">...</td>
        <td width="180" id="OuterRightCell">...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I want to control the width of #OuterLeftCell and #OuterRightCell but it is hard-coded in the html that is returned. How would I change these values?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily override the inline settings via CSS. For example, here is the equivalent CSS for the current inline settings (define in the `HEAD` section of your page, via your .master or a page layout):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #OuterZoneTable {
        /* Control overall table width */
        width: 100%;
    }

    #OuterLeftCell {
        width: auto;
    }

    #OuterRightCell {
        width: 180px;
    }
</style>
```

Now if you wanted to make both cells take up half the available space, you'd change their definitions both to be `width:50%`. Hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Sadly does not seem to be working. I imagine the in-line width takes a higher precedence than CSS.

Comment: Try adding !important to the CSS declarations. Example: `width: 50% !important;`